# Linux (SOL) loop until next day

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris

I got a problem with loop in overnight script.
So i got a big script, what running a night dump for all bases and then start some amount of tasks, what are required to be started at next day, because they are comparing information in bases and make some changes to it. 
This script start at 00:35 and needed to end until 6:00 am next day. But bases goes bigger and bigger, and only one reason to end it in time - start dumping bases earlier, than now.
So i made some improvment, what i found in internet and added in script a loop to check if new day was started:

```
while [ $(date "+%H") -ge 21 ]; do
    echo "`date` - NOT OK" >> /tfiles/Log/logtest.txt
    sleep 120
done
echo "`date` - OK" >> /tfiles/Log/logtest.txt
```

A question is - does this loop works, if bases dumping long enough to reach next day. I mean - if we starting this script at 21:00, dumping ends at 00:10, then loop checks what day it is, and start waiting until next day.

And one more question, i can't find, what does it mean option -ge 21?

In summary script looks like:

1. start at 21:00
2. dump
3. loop check if it reaches next day
4. wait until next day
5. jobs what are needed to be started at next day
6. end of script running something like

Comment: After 0:10 in the morning, the script does a busy loop until it is 21:00 again.  However, it is very odd to run a script like this. What if (say, because of a reboot), the script gets aborted? Wouldn't it make more sense to set up a cron job at 21:00 every day.

Comment: I m completly forgot write about my crontab setup, script not working every moment, it start by crontab at 21 and ends on next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition in the while is

```
while [ $(date "+%H") -ge 21 ]
```

That says "loop this as long as `[` (an alias for `test`) returns true."
`test` uses `-ge` to check whether the left operand (`$(date "+%H")`) is *greater than or equal to* the right operand (21).

`date` reads its argument, `"+%H"`, as a format specifier dictating output as the hour only, in 24hr format, so at 9pm it will report 21. The test will be true, so it will enter the loop, print to the logfile, and sleep for two minutes. 10pm is 22, 11pm, is 23, so until midnight is should work fine.

At midnight the hour becomes 00, so the test fails and the loop falls out.

I think what you really want is a [`crontab`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) entry that defined the required behavior - c.f. the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).

Comment: I forget to write about crontab. I setted launch of the script in 21in it - it's not a script working through day, it's just a script, what starts at 21:00 by crontab and ends after midnight.
So, right now, i m thinking about vairable, what can at start of the script type a start date, and add one more loop with check of what this date not equal to tomorrow date.
Something like startdate must be lesser then date in loop check.

Comment: Why do you need a busy wait, until it is 9 pm, if you start it by cron anyway at that time?

Comment: Here a little misunderstanding happened, i'm already have this script in crontab at 9:00
I olnly need second part of scripit to start in next day.

Comment: 2nd script, 2nd crontab. Write any state you need carried over somewhere and load it in the 2nd script.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand the question fully, but at least this part:

-ge is explained in man bash:

> arg1 OP arg2 OP is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge. These
>   arithmetic binary operators return true if arg1 is equal to, not equal
>   to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or
>   equal to arg2, respectively. Arg1 and arg2 may be positive or negative
>   integers.